# Chart object has no attribute 'add' error in xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I'm trying to create a chart object using xlwings.

```
import xlwings as xw
xw.Chart.add()
```

I get the following error:

> type object 'Chart' has no attribute 'add'

I also cannot find documentation for the Chart object, chart API in xlwings. It would be really helpful if someone could share that with me.

Comment: The xlwings API is a reflection of the C# API.  For a list of methods, see Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.chartclass?view=excel-pia

Comment: See the official API docs, it's `mysheet.charts.add()`: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#charts